# How to use slash commands on a discord bot?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, discord.py

I know that recently, discord added the ability for bots to use slash commands. I checked the developer portal and found their resource in the documentation for discord.py. Here is the example they provided:

```py
import requests


url = "https://discord.com/api/v8/applications/<my_application_id>/commands"

json = {
    "name": "blep",
    "description": "Send a random adorable animal photo",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "animal",
            "description": "The type of animal",
            "type": 3,
            "required": True,
            "choices": [
                {
                    "name": "Dog",
                    "value": "animal_dog"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cat",
                    "value": "animal_cat"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Penguin",
                    "value": "animal_penguin"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "only_smol",
            "description": "Whether to show only baby animals",
            "type": 5,
            "required": False
        }
    ]
}

# For authorization, you can use either your bot token
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bot 123456"
}

# or a client credentials token for your app with the applications.commands.update scope
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer abcdefg"
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json)
```

What is meant by <my_application_id>? When I tried basically copying and pasting this code for my bot I couldn't get it to work, it kept saying I wasn't authorized. How can I successfully add a slash command to my application, and how can I get a bot to respond to slash command input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this libary it is easy to use and it works.

https://github.com/eunwoo1104/discord-py-slash-command
Have a great day

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll let you know if I have a problem with that.

Comment: Does this library handle registering/creating new commands, or just reacting to when someone uses the commands? Either way, it's a great tool, but I need a way to register my bot's commands.

Comment: It does mention how to do this [in their docs](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#frequently-asked-questions). This includes adding slash commands as well as deleting them.

Comment: With all of your helpful comments, I got it to work. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

## Discord has Implemented Buttons, Select Menus, and Slash Commands.

Buttons and Select menus are available in discord.py 2.0, (You need to upgrade to it with this command: `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`)

I would suggest using a module called `discord_slash`, it supports Buttons and Dropdowns, unlike a ton of other slash command modules.